# Load test doesn't show more than 4GB for Working Set PerformanceCounter

Tags: c#, performance, performance-testing, load-testing, performancecounter

I'm trying to create [load test](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release) to some application. **And I want to get the memory usage for just the process of my application**. To do so I added `Process / Working Set` to my counter set

[image]

The problem is the `Working Set` `PerformanceCounter` read the values in bytes and didn't count values more than `4294967296` which equals to 4 GB

[image]

But my application "runs in 64-bit mode" uses **more than 4 GB of the memory**
It's clear from TaskManager I see that it takes about 6GB but this value **doesn't appear in the load test Graph**.

So how to create customized [PerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to act exactly like `Process/Working Set` one but using **Kilobytes** instead of bytes I may get the real values. Or any other solution that enables me to calculate **how much my application use memory in the load test.**

Comment: Why not just take the output of the normal one and divide by `2 << 10`

Comment: I'm not reading the value programmatically. I'm just using counter sets in the load test

Comment: You can create your own counters that supply exactly the value you want. Microsoft has pages about how to create custom performance counters.

Comment: If you want to count beyond 4294967296 then your program must run as a 64-bit process.  That's easy to do, right-click your EXE Project > Properties > Build tab.  Untick the Prefer 32-bit checkbox, ensure the Platform target is AnyCPU.

Comment: @HansPassant It actually runs in 64-bit mode and when I track its performance in TaskManager I see that it take about 6GB but this value doesn't appear in the load test Graph

Comment: Not the program you are trying test, the one that is displaying these statistics.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If you're running the 64-bit version of performance monitor (`c:\windows\system32\perfmon.exe`) it has no trouble displaying counter values in excess of 2^32. What software are you using to track the counter? Keep in mind that Visual Studio is a 32-bit application, and will likely remain so for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm using Load test as I mentioned in the question which is run inside Visual Studio  https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release

Comment: This sounds a lot like you want someone to write code for you. Is there something about [the tutorials and examples on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184425(v=vs.90).aspx) that you find confusing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I found a solution. Thanks for all your comments, all of them, were very helpful.*

**The first step** is the normal installing new `PerformanceCounterCategory` just the most important thing is to set it as `PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance`
e.g.

```
var countersToCreate = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
var memoryCounterData = new CounterCreationData("Memory Usage", "Memory Usage", PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64);
countersToCreate.Add(memoryCounterData);
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("KB Memory Usage", "KB Memory Usage", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, countersToCreate);
```

**The next step** is to have simple windows service or console application that should read the values for each process from `process.WorkingSet64` and set them to your `PerformanceCounter`. **This application or Service should run while you're running your load test and of course in x64 mode**. 
e.g.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            var memoryUsage = new PerformanceCounter("KB Memory Usage", "Memory Usage", process.ProcessName, false);
            memoryUsage.RawValue = process.WorkingSet64/1024;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [`PerformanceCounter.RawValue Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.rawvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the counter type is a 32-bit size and you attempt to set this property to a value that is too large to fit, the property truncates the value to 32 bits.

So you have to use a correct [`PerformanceCounterType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountertype(v=vs.110).aspx) (those, suffixed with `64`).

Comment: Voting down without leaving any comment has never been useful for anyone. Dear downvoters, please be so kind and explain to me what you do not like about my hint. Thanks.